# Does any know a good Bluetooth framework that works on Linux not under GPL?

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth

Does any know a good Bluetooth framework that works on Linux not under GPL?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.javabluetooth.com/development_kits.html) lists a number of Bluetooth frameworks for Java.  One is LGPL (not GPL), others are commercial.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end we end up with bluecove.